# Which Ruby HTTP client to use inside Sidekiq jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, timeout, sidekiq

We've just had an issue where all our Sidekiq workers hung for the whole day (i.e. until we restarted them) on a job that makes a request to Facebook using Net::HTTP library (via Koala and Faraday), even though we had both open and read timeouts set. I thought about wrapping the code inside the job in `Timeout.timeout`, but then I found out about http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/ and http://blog.headius.com/2008/02/rubys-threadraise-threadkill-timeoutrb.html. Turns out that Net::HTTP and Excon libraries also use `Timeout.timeout` to handle open/connect timeouts.

Is it safe to use an HTTP library that uses `Timeout` module inside a Sidekiq job? If not, then which libraries one could use?

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past, I don't remember the library I used, I think I've used open-uri, the problem was that it was opening ports randomly to communicate and there were conflicts when you were opening too many. So I had to create a queue and manually set the communication port for each process to prevent port override / timeouts. Maybe that's the problem you have as well.